# Can someone please explain to he how this code works?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to build a 2D array out of 1D array of chars, where every time I encounter a newline, the word (including that newline) is copied to the 2D array element. Here is the code, and this is exactly what I need but I have few questions about it.

Let me remind you that this is just a part of the code from my program
so numChars is just the number of chars in the chars array.
   numWords is just the number of words that I have.
   and words is declared as char **words.

```
int k=0;
int i=0;

char** words = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * numWords);
words[k] = chars;
while(i < numChars)
{
    if(chars[i] == '\n')
    {
        k++;
        words[k] = (chars+i+1);
    }
    i++;
}
```

question #1: what does the first `words[k] = chars` do ?
question #2: can someone explain to me how this line works `words[k] = (chars+i+1);`

Thank you very much, and sorry for the rookie question.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's almost impossible to suggest anything useful with bits and pieces of code.

Comment: we dont know the answer to the first one because we cant see what chars is

Comment: What does the debugger show you when you step through the code?

Comment: As you have taken out essential parts of the code (like all of the hints what `chars` are, it is kind of difficult to answer your questions.

Comment: Well, for one this exhibits a beautiful buffer-overflow if the number of `'\n` chars in the input `chars` buffer exceeds `numWords`. So I guess the short answer is: poorly.

Answer (score 0):

if I assume that chars is an array of the input characters

```
words[k] = chars;
```

sets the first word pointer to point to the first character of the input. It would be clearer to write

```
words[0] = chars;
```

next

```
words[k] = (chars+i+1);
```

sets the kth word pointer to point at the i + 1th character in chars. This wont actually do what you need since the various word pointers point at the correct starting character but there is no terminating '\0' for each 'word'. So if you printf each words[i] you will get

```
the cat sat on the mat
cat sat on the mat
sat on the mat
....
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. \0 termination is one of the problems that I am getting actually, because In the assignment that I am given, for some reason they want me to treat \0 as a regular character and not a NULL character for termination.